# Python: "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"... with the file it found?

Tags: python, macos

I'm writing a Python script where part of its function is to find the last modified file of a specific kind.  In my case, it's for the last modified screen saver plist file on Mac OS X.  Below are the bits of code which deal with this:

```
import os

PlistFolder = "Library/Preferences/ByHost"
MacPlistPath = os.path.join(HomeFolder, PlistFolder)
PlistSSMac = max([f for f in os.listdir(MacPlistPath) if f.lower().endswith('.plist') and f.lower().startswith('com.apple.screensaver.')], key=os.path.getmtime)
```

When I run it, however, it gives me an error while returning exactly what I wanted it to find...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcn_test.py", line 29, in <module>
    MacPlistFile = max([f for f in os.listdir(MacPlistPath) if f.lower().endswith('.plist') and f.lower().startswith('com.apple.screensave
r.')], key=os.path.getmtime)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 62, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'com.apple.screensaver.097EBF05-D7B5-5FD6-A031-12734A82135D.plist'
```

Any ideas on what causes this and how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listdir` won't prepend the directory name, so you cannot pass `os.path.getmtime` as-is.

Wrap it with a lambda and join with the source directory:

```
MacPlistFile = max((f for f in os.listdir(MacPlistPath) if f.lower().endswith('.plist') and f.lower().startswith('com.apple.screensaver.')), key=lambda f : os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(MacPlistPath,f)))
```

But looking at the bigger picture, you'd be even better off with `glob.glob` and a wildcard:

```
import glob
MacPlistFile = os.path.basename(max(glob.glob(os.path.join(MacPlistPath,"com.apple.screensaver.*.plist")), key=os.path.getmtime))
```

`glob.glob` returns the full path, so now you can use `os.path.getmtime` directly as a key. You just have to perform an `os.path.basename` in the end to get only the last modified file name.

Aside: no need to create a *list comprehension*. A *generator comprehension* is enough for `max` to work efficiently.